# How to write a nonlinear polynomial system in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, computational-geometry

I have a nonlinear system like the following example

```
eqs={b1 Subscript[K, M] u[1][t] - k21 Subscript[K, M] x[1][t] - 
  Subscript[V, M] x[1][t] + b1 u[1][t] x[1][t] - k21 x[1][t]^2 + 
  k12 Subscript[K, M] x[2][t] + k12 x[1][t] x[2][t] - 
  Subscript[K, M] Derivative[1][x[1]][t] - 
  x[1][t] Derivative[1][x[1]][t], 
 k21 x[1][t] - k02 x[2][t] - k12 x[2][t] - Derivative[1][x[2]][t], 
 c1 x[1][t] - y[1][t]};
```

I would like to write it in matrix form with the ordering

```
varorder={(x[1]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t], Derivative[1][x[2]][t], 
 Derivative[1][x[1]][t], x[2][t], x[1][t], (y[1]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t],
  Derivative[1][y[1]][t], Derivative[1][u[1]][t], y[1][t], u[1][t]};
```

for the linear state, I have used the below command

```
coMat = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eqs, varorder][[2]]
```

But now the problem is that I would like to have some variables as coefficients, unfortunately, this command does not work anymore, Actually, I need something like

```
Derivative[1][x[1]][t]+ b1 u[1][t] x[1][t] - k21 x[1][t]^2 -> {0,0,1,0,-k21 x[1]+b1 u[1][t],0,...,0}
```

Comment: TIP: don't use subscripts or `K` as a variable name.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the output to be? It would also be easier if you used different variables than x[1] and x[2] in your example (i.e. x1 or x2).